# Merging Flow with one shot data

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a `Flow` that fetches items from database (this is easy using Room), and then I have another data source which is an API. I can call this API (they don't implement Flows because it is an old Java API) which will give me other set of items (same type as the database ones).

My Room database returns a `Flow<List<MyItem>>` already and I can show it, and it gets updated on adding/deleting items, but now I need to fetch the other set of items from the API and I don't know how to proceed. Furthermore, I only can fetch them if the user has logged in (i.e., if the user has a valid token).

So, in order to use `combine`, I have used the function `callbackFlow` to get the items as a `Flow` and then I combine the flow from database and the flow from the API. However, I don't know how to update this flow from the API when the user logs in (fetch items) or logs out (clear items).

In my ideal world, I would have a `LiveData` which has the session token, and if it is null I would clear the flow and otherwise I would make the petition to the API, but I don't know how to implement this, I am new to the `Flow` concept and components.

Edit: I tried the following, but I don't know if I'm on the right path.

```
override fun getItemsAsFlow(): Flow<List<Item>>{
        return flow {
            val isLoggedIn = _loggedIn.value ?: false
            var id = 1000000L
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                val list = ItemAPIManager.getItems().map {
                    Item(id = id++, name = it.name)
                }
                emit(list)
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Update: Based on @Tenfour04 answer, I updated my code. My API provider does this:

```
override fun getItemsAsFlow(): Flow<List<Item>> {
        val items =
        _loggedIn.flatMapLatest { loggedIn ->
            if(loggedIn) {
                callbackFlow {
                    var id = 1000000L
                    val list = ItemAPIManager.getItems().map {
                        Item(id = id++, name = it.name)
                    }
                    trySend(list)
                    awaitClose()
                }
            }
            else emptyFlow()
        }
        return items
    }
```

My ViewModel where all these merge to create a `RecyclerView` has this function:

```
private val _databaseItems: Flow<List<Item>> = databaseProvider.getItemsAsFlow()
private val _otherDatabaseItems: Flow<List<Item>> = databaseProvider.getSpecialItemsAsFlow()
private val _apiItems: Flow<List<Item>> = apiProvider.getItemsAsFlow()

private fun fetchItems(): LiveData<List<ItemViewModel>> {
        val itemViewModelFlow = _databaseItems.combine<List<Item>, List<Item>, List<ItemViewModel>>(_otherDatabaseItems) { dbItems1, dbItems2 ->
            val retList = arrayListOf<ItemViewModel>()
            if (settingsProvider.areTheOtherItemsEnabled) {
                retList.addAll(createViewData(dbItems2))
            }
            retList.addAll(createViewData(dbItems1))
            return@combine retList
        }.combine<List<ItemViewModel>, List<Item>, List<ItemViewModel>>(_apiItems) { itemViewModels, apiItems ->
            val retList = arrayListOf<ItemViewModel>()
            retList.addAll(itemViewModels)
            retList.addAll(createViewData(apiItems))
            return@combine retList
        }

        return itemViewModelFlow.asLiveData()
    }
```

The fact that I have two database lists is not relevant here, we can treat them as one. Basically, if a setting is enabled, these will get shown to the user, otherwise they won't.

The `createViewData` function just transforms a list of items into a list of item view models that are used in the `RecyclerView`.

Now if I'm logged in when I start the app, I can see the two database item lists, and I can see the API items, but if I log out I still can see the API items. Furthermore, if I'm logged out I cannot even see the database items (which I should).

Thank you for your patience, as I'm still learning `Flows`.

Comment: `flow.flatMapLatest`, probably

Comment: Do I need to keep a reference to the flow in my API provider?

Comment: Do not combine one-off flow with hot flow. Write the retrieved results into DB to trigger a re-load by Room.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what do you mean by "downstream"? And yes, that's pretty much it. When logged in I want to emit a Flow of items, and when logged out, I want to emit an empty Flow.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so should I write the results to database? Notice that these cannot be accessible if the user is logged out from the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt in your edit will not change behavior when logged in state changes unless you cancel and recollect it.

I’m on my phone so I might make a syntax error, but this would do what you’ve described. I don’t really understand what you’re doing with the items in your database (like whether they are are a cache of previously fetched API items or if they are persistent supplementary items) so I left that out.

```
// In your API provider/manager class:

// update this when login state changes
private val isLoggedIn = MutableStateFlow(false)

// The callbackFlow that fetches API items
private val fetchedItems: Flow<List<MyItem>> = TODO()

// Flow that starts collecting and emitting from fetchedItems at
// login and emits an empty list when logout occurs. 
val loggedInItems = isLoggedIn.flatMapLatest { loggedIn ->
    if (loggedIn) fetchedItems else flowOf(emptyList()) 
}
```

If the callback flow depends on credentials provided by login, then the `isLoggedIn` flow might be expanded to use a class that wraps login state with those credentials, and the callback flow might be more naturally defined inside the flatMapLatest flow so it can use those credentials when they become available. Something like this:

```
sealed interface LoginState {
    object LoggedOut: LoginState
    data class LoggedIn(val token: String): LoginState
}

private val loginState = MutableStateFlow<LoginState>(LoggedOut)

val loggedInItems = loginState.flatMapLatest { loginState ->
    when (loginState) {
        LoggedOut -> flowOf(emptyList())
        is LoggedIn -> callbackFlow {
            val token = loginState.token
            //...
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Login state must be a state flow or can I do it with LiveData and observe? I will try and will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: You could wrap your live data in a flow using `asFlow()` so you can call `flatMapLatest()` on it.

Comment: I did the thing on your first example (because logged in is just a boolean) and it is working! However, when I log out, the list is not updated (it should remove the API items). I'm updating my question with the new code, so if you could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be awesome!

Comment: I updated the question again, feel free to provide more details if you can, because I think I'm almost there but I still don't quite get the gist of Flows.

Comment: You need `flowOf(emptyList())`, not `emptyFlow()` or it won't emit anything when you log out. I can look at the other stuff you posted later. Do you want to see database items regardless of API login status?

Comment: Yes, login status should only affect API items, not database items

Comment: It is working with `flowOf(emptyList())` but the databaseFlow2 is not updating the `RecyclerView` unless I get out of the activity and come back.